# Navigation Drawer header image does not appear after asking from camera or gallery

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I made a base activity for navigation purpose common to all activities.Although it is working fine. I wanted to set image on the header which will ask whether to take it from gallery or camera or via facebook.

Getting image from facebook is working but the problem is if i select the image from alert dialogue then nothing happens and also the on click works for the list not for an image clicked.

This is my code:

```
 private void selectImage() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder( BaseActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Choose Image Source");
        profilepic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        builder.setItems(new CharSequence[]{"Take a Photo",
                        "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"},
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                intent1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                                startActivityForResult(intent1, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                // GET IMAGE FROM THE GALLERY
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser(intent, ""),PICK_IMAGE);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                dialog.dismiss();

                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }


    public Uri setImageUri() {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }


    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                System.out.println("path" + selectedImagePath);
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));

            } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
                System.out.println("path" + selectedImagePath);
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }
    }


    public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of
            // 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                    && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: what's the value of path in case of Capture Image

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
       public void selectImage() {
          final String[] items = new String[]{"Camera", "Gallery"};
    final Integer[] icons = new Integer[]{R.drawable.ic_camera, R.drawable.ic_gallery};
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapterWithIcon(getActivity(), items, icons);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Select Picture")
    .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Camera")) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

            } else if (items[item].equals("Gallery")) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 19) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
                } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
                }
            }
        }
    }).show();

}    


    // get result after selecting image from Gallery
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURIForGallery(selectedImageUri);
            decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            profileImage.setImageBitmap(photo);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), photo);

            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
            File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
            decodeFile(finalFile.toString());
        }
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURIForGallery(Uri uri) {
        if (uri == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }


    // decode image
    public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);
        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;
        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

        profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

Comment: no still the same. image is not appearing not even the image background

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas..now I am providing you the tested full solution of your problem

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas..Is your problem is resolved your not?

Comment: no not at all. I tried my own same code in different project and it is working fine.

Comment: @PriyankaMinhas..Have you tried my updated full code?